# Math.Net how to generate vector of exponential distribution random numers

Tags: c#, exponential, mathnet-numerics, exponential-distribution

I am trying to generate random numbers with exponential distribution. I have found Math.NET NuGet package. It looks nice, but I can not figure out how to generate a vector of these kind of data.

I have included the reference and tried something like this (inspired by official website) - I know that Uniform will not generate Exponential values.:

```
 Generate.Uniform(100);
```

However I get: "Generate is does not exist in current context. "

I have also tried:

```
 Random rnd= new Random();
 double[] samples;
 double lambda = 0.1;
 Exponential.Samples(rnd, samples,lambda);
```

Here I get "Invalid expression term ')' " and " ; expected" on the last line.

Comment: You could generate it without using Math.Net: https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/generating-exponentially-distributed-data-in-a-given-range-min-to-max/

Comment: so, basically, you get a compiler error?

Comment: you can use the Infer.Net pakckage.

Answer (score 0):

The `Samples` function expects the array to be allocated already, so you can reuse it repeatedly. It will fill the full array.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double lambda = 0.1;

double[] samples = new double[200];
Exponential.Samples(rnd, samples, lambda);
```

However, you've asked for a vector, not an array:

```
Vector<double> v = CreateVector.Random<double>(200, new Exponential(lambda, rnd));
```

The error you got is a C# syntax error unrelated to Math.NET Numerics (and not present in the code you actually posted here). For `Generate` you need to open the `MathNet.Numerics` namespace.

Comment: Thank you :). One more question. How to set range of generated numbers. Foe rxample between 0 and 1?

Comment: With uniform distribution: `ContinuousUniform.Samples(rnd, samples, 0.0, 1.0);` Or do you mean with an exponential distribution but filtered to 0.0-1.0?

Comment: Yes, I mean with an exponential distribution from 0.0 - 1.0.

Comment: Assuming a given lambda that would normally produce numbers outside of the range, you could do something along the lines of `Exponential.Samples(rnd, lambda).Where(x => x <= 1.0).Take(200).ToArray()`. Of course, technically such filtered numbers are then no longer strictly exponentially distributed.